# Android error: "APK NOT INSTALLED" in Android 2.3.x

Tags: java, android

My app seems to working in Android 4.0 also in emulator. but when I tried in other device(2.3) it showing "APK NOT INSTALLED" :(
Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ex.live"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ex.live.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: do you have any previously installed same app in the device?

Comment: APK installation using `adb` could tell you the cause of the problem. `adb install "/blablabla/folder/myApp.apk`

Comment: How are you installing it? command line or through eclipse?

Comment: @Sreekanthss no, it was a fresh install.

Comment: @Glenn-- actually I tried in my emulator it works fine

Comment: @Yasir im installing directly from sdcard.

Comment: No, I mean install the app using command prompt/terminal.

Comment: @jquery404 I mean this way. http://adbshell.com/upload/adb-install-r.jpg

Comment: @Glenn-- i just tried it . but same result. :(

Comment: can you post the result you got from Glenn's way?